# Does the Java 9 Module system support optional dependencies?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

**Background**

In maven, an artifact can declare a dependency with

```
<optional>true</optional>
```

which means that the dependency is not required, but can be used if present.

[The State of the Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/) seems to specify that a module can only read modules it has required.

**Questions**

- Does the Java 9 module system indeed not support optional dependencies?
- Why not?
- What alternatives to optional dependencies does the Java 9 module system provide?

**Use Case**

I have a framework that integrates various libraries that may or may not be used by an application. Currently, this framework is a single JAR that reflects upon the classpath to skip integration code for absent libraries.

I guess we could split this into a separate module for each configuration, but this would cause a combinatorial explosion in the number of JARs, because we'd not only need a separate JAR for each optional dependency, but also a separate JAR for most pairs of optional dependencies ...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, [optional dependencies are supported](https://blog.codefx.org/java/module-system-optional-dependencies/). Quoting from [the original proposal](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jpms-spec-experts/2016-June/000306.html):

> Extend the language of module declarations to allow the `static` modifier to be used on a `requires` directive, with the following meanings:
>
> - At compile time, `requires static M` expresses a mandatory dependence.  It is an error if a suitable module cannot be found amongst the observable modules and resolved.
> - In phases after compile time, `requires static M` expresses an optional dependence.  The module system will not search the observable modules for a suitable module during resolution, but if the resulting module graph contains a suitable module then it will add the appropriate readability edge prior to doing the usual post-resolution sanity checks. [...]
>
> Thus a hypothetical module declaration of the form
>
> ```
> module joda.beans {
>     requires static joda.collect;
>     ...
> }
> ```
>
> would ensure that the `joda.collect` module is available at compile time, so that code in the `joda.beans` module that refers to `joda.collect` can be compiled without any fuss.  It would not, however, guarantee that `joda.collect` is available at link time or run time.

(In the meantime, [official documentation was created for that feature](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/doc/topics/optional.html).)

I wrote [a demo](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-jigsaw-advent-calendar/tree/05-optional-dependency) for this. The interesting tidbits are the `module-info.java` of the module declaring the optional dependencies...

```
module org.codefx.demo.advent {
    // list the required modules
    requires org.codefx.demo.advent.calendar;
    // with 'static' the factories are only required at compile time;
    // to be present at run time either other modules most require them
    // or they must be added with the '--add-modules' command line option
    requires static org.codefx.demo.advent.factory.chocolate;
    requires static org.codefx.demo.advent.factory.quote;
}
```

... and the code within the same module that wants to access types from its optional dependencies. It has to written so that it fails graciously if the types `ChocolateFactory` and/or `QuoteFactory` are absent:

```
private static List<SurpriseFactory> createSurpriseFactories() {
    return Stream.of(
            createChocolateFactoryIfAccessible(),
            createQuoteFactoryIfAccessible())
            .flatMap(Optional::stream)
            .collect(toList());
}

private static Optional<SurpriseFactory> createChocolateFactoryIfAccessible() {
    try {
        return Optional.of(new ChocolateFactory());
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError er) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}

private static Optional<SurpriseFactory> createQuoteFactoryIfAccessible() {
    try {
        return Optional.of(new QuoteFactory());
    } catch (NoClassDefFoundError er) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Finally, the command line can be used to define which modules the app launches with:

```
$java \
    --add-modules org.codefx.demo.advent.factory.chocolate,org.codefx.demo.advent.factory.quote \
    -p mods -m org.codefx.demo.advent
```

It is of course also possible that other modules require them non-optionally, which forces the JVM to include them into the module graph.

Comment: Wasnt sure whether the openjdk-proposal was implemented unchanged or some last-minute renaming occurred. Thus here another official documentation directly from oracle: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7